# How to do a conditional https request?

Tags: node.js

This is basically what I'm trying to do::

```
var sendRequest= false;  //may be true

https.request(request_params, function(response){  //only sends a request if sendRequest == true
    //do something with response if request has been sent      
    someObjWithCallback.itsfunction(its_params, function(resp){
          //do something with response
    }        
}
```

How do I make sure that the https.request only runs when the sendRequest condition is true.

Note: someObjWithCallback.itsfunction(..) must run in either case (sendRequest is true or false) . Hence the callback function must run in any case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an if statement to check the variable:

```
if (sendRequest) {
  https.request(request_params, function(response){  //only sends a request if sendRequest == true
    //do something with response if request has been sent      
    someObjWithCallback.itsfunction(its_params, function(resp){
          //do something with response
    }        
  })
}
```

or take advantage of the && operator (and read [this excellent article](https://blog.usejournal.com/mastering-javascripts-and-logical-operators-fd619b905c8f))

```
sendRequest && https.request(request_params, function(response){  //only sends a request if sendRequest == true
    //do something with response if request has been sent      
    someObjWithCallback.itsfunction(its_params, function(resp){
          //do something with response
    })     
}
```

or mess around with ternary expressions (but only if you wanted to do something *instead* of the request when it is false)

```
sendRequest ? https.request(request_params, function(response){  //only sends a request if sendRequest == true
    //do something with response if request has been sent      
    someObjWithCallback.itsfunction(its_params, function(resp){
          //do something with response
    }        
}) : console.log('lol, don't actually do this if you dont have an "else" condition...')
```